# Как зашифрован mac-адрес сетевой карты

Tags: шифрование

Ребят!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким алгоритмом может быть зашифрована эта строка:
303935831866157913921508571334258983887

В этой строке зашифрован мак-адрес сетевой карты: 00-22-4D-69-9D-47 (возможно без "тире").

Очень нужно узнать как это было сделано! 
Возможно за деньги...

Спасибо!

Comment: если Вы готовы платить деньги, то обратитесь к тем, кто это дело шифровал. Может и расскажут.